# Are Jews fleeing France able to flee to any countries other than Israel?

Tags: france, asylum, antisemitism

French Jews, and Jews from many if not all countries, are able to emigrate to Israel, the only Jewish-majority country, as a result of the law of return.

Apart from Israel, are there any countries which French Jews can emigrate to on the basis that they’re facing out of control hate crimes against them in France? Assume they are just average Jewish French people, rather than having family ties or extraordinary skills.

The article [Jews Are Fleeing France in Droves As Anti-Semitism Goes Unchecked](http://jewishjournal.com/news/world/231489/jews-fleeing-france-droves-anti-semitism-goes-unchecked/) only mentions them migrating to Israel.

Comment: Are you asking about countries where they can legally gain asylum? Or more which countries they’re immigrating to?

Comment: Are you defining emigration to include the EU's freedom of movement right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75193/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-grimm-are-jews-fleeing-france-able-to-flee-to-a).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, many countries have open or semi-open immigration policies.

- My [answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/25240/115) lists countries with most open policies. You merely need a small (by Western standards) guaranteed income to immigrate without any reasons.
- Putin [officially told European Jewish Congress that he welcomes European Jews fleeing anti-Semitism in Europe into Russia](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2016/01/20/putin-says-europes-jews-should-move-to-russia/?utm_term=.d5f66831bf85). I would guess that whether there's a formal legal framework or not, that means if anyone wants to do so, they will be allowed, if only for PR/propaganda purposes.
- USA and some other countries provide avenues for legal immigration. USA has both diversity visa program, and investment based immigration, and guest worker program. Canada has merit based immigration, afaik so does Australia?
- As far as I understand [EU rules](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/who-does-what/more-information/explaining-the-rules-why-are-there-eu-rules-and-national-rules_en), you can migrate to ANY EU country for 3 months and then stay if you find a job since France is part of EU.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm what does France's diversity or lack thereof have to do with anything?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm As I understand it, diversity [refers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa#Geographical_distribution) to the diversity of regions of origin, not to the diversity *inside* the individual countries. The idea seems to be to somewhat average out from which continents immigrants come / increase immigration from countries with low immigration in the past (eg historically, it was among other intended to increase Irish immigration).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Tim is correct.  The program is intended to increase diversity in the US.  The diversity of people's countries of origins is irrelevant.  To effect the program's goal, certain countries are disqualified; they are chosen solely on the number of immigrants who have come from those countries in the recent past.  For this purpose, people are considered to be from a country if they were born there; citizenship is not taken into account.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/why-does-the-u-s-grant-visas-via-lottery/1415#1415

Answer (score 9):

French Jews are not able to emigrate to Israel on the basis of being under threat of hate crime. They are able to Emigrate as Jewish People. Israel has a law which allows for most Jewish people to immigrate, regardless of their asylum status.

I'm not aware of any countries that are considering or have accepted French refugees. Of course it is hard to prove a negative, especially when French Jewish people have multiple options that are better than asylum.

The EU allows freedom of movement and of labour throughout its member states. By virtue of being EU citizens, a French Jewish person can, without claiming asylum, live and work in Belgium, Spain, Germany, the UK, Poland, Romania: 27 states apart from France, I shall not list them all.

Beyond this there are numerous countries that are happy to accept relatively wealthy Europeans, again without claiming asylum. This is importat because asylum is the worst possible immigration status. With Israel and Europe both accepting immigration, It would be surprising if French Jew would be attempting to use the asylum route in anything but the  smallest numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Most French citizens can emigrate to any EU country of their choice, and that includes French Jews, obviously.

Claiming asylum for example in Germany is practically impossible for French citizens. Germany would - just like France - say there is no evidence for "out of control hate crimes against Jews in France" - nothing that the French police wouldn't handle.

Just in case this isn't blatantly obvious: French Jews would have no problem entering Germany, getting a job, leading their life, but they wouldn't get asylum.

Answer (score -1):

> Are there any countries which French Jews can emigrate to on the basis that they’re facing out of control hate crimes against them in France, apart from Israel?

1. USA
2. Canada
3. Russia
4. Ukraine
5. Argentina

These should be top 5 choices outside Western Europe.

Canada would be more convenient as the province of Quebec speaks the French language.

See: [Jewish population by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_population_by_country#Table)

Comment: Just because they were able to emigrate there in the past for various reasons doesn't mean that they're able to emigrate there now on the basis of them fleeing hate crimes against them.

Comment: Also, many French people would not agree that the language spoken in Quebec is French :-)

Comment: @jamesqf, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec#Language

Comment: @why: I think you misunderstood the comment. Quebec does speak French, but a variant that is somewhat different from French as spoken in France (similar to English having American, British, Indian, Australian etc. variants).

Comment: @chirlu most importantly, why failed to understand that it was a joke.

Comment: @why: See https://www.talkinfrench.com/canadian-french-difference/ Quebecois is well on its way to becoming a different language - at least according to the French :-)

Comment: What if french jews do not care about having other jews around ? Calling this a top 5 choice looks like a wild guess